# VkSurfaceKHR pointer's value changes after a function call without any explicit assignments

Tags: c++, c, vulkan

This is the abridged error message from Vulkan's validation layers

```
Invalid VkSurfaceKHR Object 0x1000000002.
Objects: 1
        [0] 0x1000000002, type: 1000000000, name: NULL
```

thrown by this function

```
populateQueueFamilies(&physicalDevice, &queueFamilyIndicesList, &queueFamilyCount, &surface);
```

Now this shouldn't happen because

```
populatePhysicalDevice(&instance, &physicalDevice, &surface);
populateQueueFamilies(&physicalDevice, &queueFamilyIndicesList, &queueFamilyCount, &surface);
```

the function before it also uses `surface` variable and doesn't throw any errors!

I wroth some print functions to see if there's something wrong with the variable and voila

```
  printf("%p\n", surface); // prints - 0x10000000001

  populatePhysicalDevice(&instance, &physicalDevice, &surface);

  printf("%p\n", surface); // prints - 0x10000000002

  populateQueueFamilies(&physicalDevice, &queueFamilyIndicesList, &queueFamilyCount, &surface);
```

I understand these sorts of problems happen when you assign to the pointer a local variable's address.

But I don't think that's what's going on here because the only function that touches `surface` var inside `populateQueueFamilies` is this one:

```
void populateSwapchainSupportDetails(SwapchainSupportDetails* gSwapchainSupportDetails,
                                     VkPhysicalDevice*        gPhysicalDevice,
                                     VkSurfaceKHR*            gSurface)
{

  VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR lCapabilities;
  uint32_t                 formatCount;
  uint32_t                 presentModeCount;

  vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR(*gPhysicalDevice, *gSurface, &lCapabilities);

  uint32_t gFormatCount;
  vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR(*gPhysicalDevice, *gSurface, &gFormatCount, VK_NULL_HANDLE);

  VkSurfaceFormatKHR lFormats[gFormatCount];
  if (gFormatCount != 0)
    {
      vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR(*gPhysicalDevice, *gSurface, &gFormatCount, lFormats);
    }

  uint32_t gPresentModeCount;

  vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfacePresentModesKHR(*gPhysicalDevice, *gSurface, &gPresentModeCount, VK_NULL_HANDLE);

  VkPresentModeKHR lPresentModes[gPresentModeCount];
  if (gPresentModeCount != 0)
    {
      vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfacePresentModesKHR(
          *gPhysicalDevice, *gSurface, &gPresentModeCount, lPresentModes);
    }

  gSwapchainSupportDetails->capabilities     = lCapabilities;
  gSwapchainSupportDetails->formatCount      = gFormatCount;
  gSwapchainSupportDetails->presentModeCount = gPresentModeCount;

  gSwapchainSupportDetails->formats = malloc(sizeof(lFormats));
  memcpy(gSwapchainSupportDetails->formats, lFormats, sizeof(lFormats));

  gSwapchainSupportDetails->formats = malloc(sizeof(lPresentModes));
  memcpy(gSwapchainSupportDetails->formats, lPresentModes, sizeof(lPresentModes));
```

There's a temporary fix that works tho:

```
VkSurfaceKHR surface1 = surface;
VkSurfaceKHR surface2 = surface;
```

and passing each `surface(number)` to different functions.

Comment: Why not `const` the parameter, and see what's what?

Comment: Would be nice to see how the input memory is allocated, and what `populatePhysicalDevice()` actually does. Psychic debugging is difficult ;) Assuming you are correct about `surface` not being modified directly, then the odds are you have some memory corruption somewhere.

Comment: @solidpixel You were right! It was memory corruption. I don't know how I missed it. Psychic debugging is difficult but apparently it works!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy was this an interesting journey that ended up in me being completely blown away by; to put it lightly - *lack* of genius.

After looking for a while, trying to debug stuff I ended up finding a really *really* stupid mistake that was causing all sorts of problems.

I got to it by using [`valgrind`](https://valgrind.org/).

I ran it using this command

```
valgrind\
       --leak-check=full\
       --leak-resolution=high\
       --show-leak-kinds=all\
       --xtree-leak=yes\
       --track-origins=yes\
       --show-mismatched-frees=yes\
```

It gave me lots of messages, here's an abridged version of them

```
Invalid write of size 8
    at <someaddress>: populateQueueFamilies ()
...
...
Invalid write of size 8
    at <someaddress>: populateQueueFamilies ()
...
...
Invalid write of size 8
    at <someaddress>: populateQueueFamilies ()
...
...
```

Invalid write means I'm writing into invalid memory location.
Some googling tells me that error message almost always occures due to wrong usage of `malloc`.

This was my `populateQueueFamilies` function

```
void populateQueueFamilies(const VkPhysicalDevice* gPhysicalDevice,
                           const VkSurfaceKHR*     surface,
                           uint32_t*               gQueueFamilyCount,
                           QueueFamilyIndices**    gQueueFamilyIndicesList)
{

  uint32_t lQueueFamilyCount;
  vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(*gPhysicalDevice, &lQueueFamilyCount, VK_NULL_HANDLE);

  VkQueueFamilyProperties lQueueFamilies[lQueueFamilyCount];
  vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(*gPhysicalDevice, &lQueueFamilyCount, lQueueFamilies);

  VkBool32 presentFamilySupported;

  (*gQueueFamilyIndicesList) = malloc(sizeof(*lQueueFamilies) * lQueueFamilyCount);

  for (int i = 0; i < lQueueFamilyCount; ++i)
    {
      QueueFamilyIndices gQueueFamilyIndices;

      populateQueueFamilyQueueIndices(lQueueFamilies[i], i, &gQueueFamilyIndices);

      presentFamilySupported = false;
      vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR(*gPhysicalDevice, i, *surface, &presentFamilySupported);

      gQueueFamilyIndices.presentFamilySupportQueueIndex = presentFamilySupported ? i : -1;

      (*gQueueFamilyIndicesList)[i] = gQueueFamilyIndices;
    }

  *gQueueFamilyCount = lQueueFamilyCount;
}
```

There that line

```
(*gQueueFamilyIndicesList) = malloc(sizeof(*lQueueFamilies) * lQueueFamilyCount);
```

In my mind I was thinking, "yes, I need size to store information from this `lQueueFamilies` array" and I allocated memory to store information from `*lQueueFamilies` times the count.

BUT that's wrong!

What I needed was

```
(*gQueueFamilyIndicesList) = malloc(sizeof(QueueFamilyIndices) * lQueueFamilyCount);
```

because I needed `gQueueFamilyIndicesList` to store a specific information from `VkQueueFamilyProperties` and not the struct itself.

I don't know how I missed it. Thanks to @krOoze for suggesting using `const` and @solidpixel to suggest that this might be corrupted memory corruption, which it was.